# Modal "Close"-Button disappears after one time closure

Tags: javascript

I am working with rails. The idea is, when a user didn't fill out all the fields in the form, the modal window appears, to point out the errors. When I first make these errors, the window apperes as I wish, with the "Close"-button underneath.

[image]

So, I click on it and the modal disappears. All good. Then I click again on the "Sign-Up"-button, still with empty fields and this is what's happening.

[image]

As you see, the "Close"-Button diasppeared. If I refresh the page and click "Sign-Up" again, "Close"-Button is there again. I am very new to JavaScript, I have no idea, what is happening. Here is my code in two files. new.js :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
   if (!modal) return;

   var close = modal.querySelector(".dismiss-close");
   var modalBody = modal.querySelector(".modal-body");
   var modalContent = modal.querySelector(".modal-content");

   function closeModal() {
     modal.style.display = "none";
     modalBody.innerHTML = "";
   }

   modalContent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();
   });

   close.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
   modal.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
});
```

and failed_modal.js.erb :

```
var errors = <%= error_messages.to_json.html_safe %>;

var errorForm = document.querySelector('#myModal');
var modalBody = errorForm.querySelector('.modal-body');
var alertElement = document.createElement('div');

alertElement.classList.add('alert');
alertElement.classList.add('alert-danger');
modalBody.appendChild(alertElement);
var errList = document.createElement('ul');
alertElement.appendChild(errList)

errors.forEach(function(error) {
   var errElement = document.createElement('li');
   errElement.innerText = error;
   errList.appendChild(errElement)
})

errorForm.style.display = "block";
```

So, how do I click away the window and get it back the same it was before, by clicking the "Sign-Up" button? Should I use "toggle"-method somehow? Thanks!

Comment: You are clearing everything from the modal with `modalBody.innerHTML = "";`. What are you filling it back up with when you press the Sign up button? I don't see that function

Comment: Oh, what should I fill it with? This is like rocket science to me. Well, the errors are still there. Only the button nicht.

Comment: Well, it should filled with the same content as the initial filling. Or you could try without emptying the HTML, so try removing the `modalBody.innerHTML = "";`

Comment: This keeps the button, but also duplicates all the errors, so first I get 4 errors, then 8, then 12 etc. How can I only keep the button without duplicating the errors-list?

Comment: I think you need an element inside the modal-body for the content(I assumed that modal-content was that, but it doesn't appear to be used other than you removing click events from it). You populate that element with the contents, then empty that element only when you're resetting it for a new modal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add id to alert div

> *after var alertElement = document.createElement('div');*
>
> alertElement.id = "alertElement";

Then instead of

> modalBody.innerHTML = "";

u can use

> modalBody.removeChild(modalBody.querySelector('#alertElement'));

which removes only div filled with errors and keeps the button.