# Bootstrap modal duplicating content untill refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

From my homepage I go to the register page by clicking "register" button, I will end up by a registration form. There, if mandatory fields are not filled out correctly, a modal would pop up and list the errors. Problem is, that the first try to register causes the modal like this :

[image]

However, if I refresh the page, modal works perfectly as supposed to. This is only happening when redirected through a register-button from a home page.

Here is my code: devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dismiss-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>          
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="center-items-register">
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages" %>

      <div class="row 1">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :first_name, class: 'required' %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="column">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :last_name, class: 'required' %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row 2">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="field email">
            <%= f.label :email, class: 'required' %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row 3">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password, class: 'required' %>
            <% if @minimum_password_length %>
            <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: 'form-control' %><br />
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :password_confirmation, class: 'required' %><br />
              <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      <div class="row buttons">
        <div class="column buttons">
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn form margin', data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#myModal" } %>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>

        <div class="column buttons">

          <% if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
            <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
          <% end %>
          <%= link_to fa_icon("facebook", text: "Sign up with facebook"), user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-social btn-facebook" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is devise/registrations/failed_modal.js.erb

```
var errors = <%= error_messages.to_json.html_safe %>;

var errorForm = document.querySelector('#myModal');
var modalBody = errorForm.querySelector('.modal-body');
var alertElement = document.createElement('div')
alertElement.id = "alertElement";
alertElement.classList.add('alert');
alertElement.classList.add('alert-danger');
modalBody.appendChild(alertElement);
var errList = document.createElement('ul');
alertElement.appendChild(errList)

errors.forEach(function(error) {
var errElement = document.createElement('li');
errElement.innerText = error;
errList.appendChild(errElement)
})

errorForm.style.display = "block";
```

And assets/javascripts/new.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
if (!modal) return;

var close = modal.querySelector(".dismiss-close");
var modalBody = modal.querySelector(".modal-body");
var modalContent = modal.querySelector(".modal-content");



window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    modalBody.removeChild(modalBody.querySelector('#alertElement'));

  }
}

function closeModal() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
  $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    modalBody.removeChild(modalBody.querySelector('#alertElement'));


}

modalContent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});

close.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
modal.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

});
```

Before I had the problem, that "close" button in my modal disappeared : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855980/modal-close-button-disappears-after-one-time-closure). Also backround didn't disappear, this is why I added this jQuery bit in my code:

```
function closeModal() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

In the console I only see the error related to autocomplete with "Algolia Places", but it should't even be here, as I actually use this autocomplete function on the next page. Here is my application.html.erb just in case. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Neigbornow</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield :meta %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'autocomplete' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= yield :css %>

  </head>
  <body>
    <% if @user.nil? %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% elsif user_signed_in? && @user.street.nil? %>
      <%= render partial: "layouts/header_address" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header_rest' %>
    <% end %>
      <%= render 'layouts/flash' %>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could the inclusion of application twice be an issue? `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` and `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` That's the only thing jumping out at me. I've had that issue before, where i was including js more than once and caused something like what you've described to happen

Comment: I think you probably want to clear out the errors and then reshow them in your js.  What it looks like you are doing is just appending over and over.  But what you want to do is remove the appended list, and then re apend the new error list.  Rightnow nothing removes the old list before appending again

Comment: First one: I do have js files from the assets and the js files, which are kind of modules, I manage with webpacker, so excluding one, will skip the part which is in one or another application.js file. Second one: I do remove it, I think. Cause when I refresh the modal does what it should. It just won't work, when redirected to a page.